# Make DictVectorizer recognize numerical values as nominal

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataset that contains the year of graduation of students as an attribute. Of course such an attribute is nominal. But `DictVectorizer` in scikit-learn will convert a value like 1988 into a number. How to make `DictVectorizer` see it as nominal?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the year values as strings, such as `{'year': '1998'}` instead of `{'year': 1998}`, according to the documentation of [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html):

> When feature values are strings, this transformer will do a binary one-hot (aka one-of-K) coding: one boolean-valued feature is constructed for each of the possible string values that the feature can take on. For instance, a feature “f” that can take on the values “ham” and “spam” will become two features in the output, one signifying “f=ham”, the other “f=spam”.

An example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

d_numerical = [{'year': 1997},
               {'year': 1998},
               {'year': 1999}]
print DictVectorizer().fit_transform(d_numerical).toarray()

d_categorical = [{'year': '1997'},
                 {'year': '1998'},
                 {'year': '1999'}]
print DictVectorizer().fit_transform(d_categorical).toarray()
```

Output:

```
[[ 1997.]
 [ 1998.]
 [ 1999.]]
[[ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

where the second case seems to be what you want.